# Using own authentication for twitter on android

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing a twitter client for android. I have used twitter4J for that.
It is successful using this. But in this flow user have to go to the twitter page to login.
Is there any way that i can customize this to my own login page.
I mean i want to login through my login ui not twitter's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer **"No you can't do it"**. Before it was like that , but now you can't create your own UI for Twitter Authentication. It will authenticate only through browser to get the Pin and use it for getting Acess token etc.

You can do one thing, can create custom Webview and load it inside of you application like

webview.load(url); // URL is authentication url.

Comment: Thanks a lot Venky... This confirmation will help me a lot. :)